# Mostrar un valor predeterminado en un listbox obtenido de una base de datos MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla que muestra una lista de datos insertados en ella:

Tabla Carrera:

[image: Tabla CARRERA]

Para mostrarlos en el formulario utilizo la siguiente funcion:

```
function bd_carrera_opciones()
{
$sql = "SELECT carr_id,carr FROM carrera ORDER BY carr ASC";
$res = sql2options( $sql );
  $zz=array();
$zz['--']='--- Seleccione la Carrera ---';
foreach($res as $id=>$valor)
{
   $zz[$id]=$valor;
}
return $zz;
}
```

apareciendo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

funciona perfectamente, uso este script:

```
carr_id: {
            required: true,
            range: [1, 99]
        },
```

para evitar que el valor elegido sea

```
'--- Seleccione la Carrera ---'
```

EL PROBLEMA:

Quisiera que apareciera un valor predeterminado es decir algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como hacerlo

Metodo para mostrar las carreras:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="esta_proy_id" class="control-label col-lg-2"><font size=3 color="red">*</font>Estado del Proyecto: </label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">

        <select class="form-control" name="esta_proy_id" id="esta_proy_id">
        <?php foreach($proyecto_estado as $i=>$proyecto_estado_temp):?>
            <option value="<?=$i?>"><?=$proyecto_estado_temp?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

     </div>
</div>
```

AL INSERTAR LA FUNCION DE EDUARDO FUENTES:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es base a que parametro se elije la carrera marcada como predefinida? hay algun atributo extra  en la base?

Comment: ¿De qué forma sabes cuál opción debes estar seleccionada?

Comment: ocurre lo siguiente: No es necesario que halla algun atributo extra que condicione una carrera en especifico, solo quisiera saber como dejarla en un valor predeterminado sin tener que usar value = 1 o value = 2, yo mismo elijo que carrera saldra pero tambien la persona podria modificarla.

Answer (score 1):

Esta solución me gusta mucho, personalmente, porque no implica ni javascript ni css. Es html puro.

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>--- Seleccione la Carrera ---</option>
    <!-- Resto de opciones aquí -->
</select>
```

Con tu actualización, quedaría algo así:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="esta_proy_id" class="control-label col-lg-2"><font size=3 color="red">*</font>Estado del Proyecto: </label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">

        <select class="form-control" name="esta_proy_id" id="esta_proy_id">
        <?php foreach($proyecto_estado as $i=>$proyecto_estado_temp):?>
            <option value="<?=$i?>"<?= ($i == '--') ? ' disabled selected' : ''?>><?=$proyecto_estado_temp?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sin embargo, con el código que muestra no podemos saber cómo está insertando los datos para hacer lo que dices.

Comment: Ciertamente, @Error404, pero en última instancia tendrá que generar html, y si el elemento option que hará las veces de `placeholder` tiene esos parámetros, cumplirá el requisito de no poder ser elegido como valor.

Comment: Sí, sin embargo a lo que yo me refería es que con el script que utiliza no tengo muy claro si los mete todos de golpe o no. Por eso no sé si se podrá introducir el atributo `selected` tan fácilmente. Creo que habría que ver el código del OP primero o que nos diga como se insertan los valores al html.

Comment: Publicare como los inserto

Comment: Si funciona a la hora de evitar que seleccionen "--seleccione carrera--", esto ya lo tengo listo.

lo que quiero es que ya este una opcion seleccionada predeterminadamente

Answer (score 1):

Complementando la respuesta de Muriano, si vas a tener una opción por defecto, la cual es dinámica en cada caso, deberías al menos tener en cada caso el id de la opción que irá por defecto en alguna variable.
Si asumimos que el id que va por defecto viene en una variable llamada $id_por_defecto, el código podría ser como el siguiente:

```
<?php foreach($proyecto_estado as $i=>$proyecto_estado_temp):?>
    <option value="<?=$i?>" 
        <?php if($i == $id_por_defecto){
            echo "SELECTED";
        }?> ><?=$proyecto_estado_temp?>
    </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Esto dejará seleccionada sólo la opción que es igual a tu $id_por_defecto.
Saludos.

Comment: solo aparece al lado del ID elegido la palabra "SELECTED" mas no lo selecciona